# Starting Neovim it gives out: notedown executable is required in order for this software to work

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

When starting Neovim in a Terminal, it gives out:

```
notedown executable is required in order for this software to work. Check whether you have needed dependencies installed in README.md
```

Also the permissions by `:w` don't work proper.
Ether I have to force with `:w!` ,or even nothing works.

I run `neovim 0.3.4 lubuntu_18.0.2_bionic`. I also tried `neovim 2.0.0` already, with the same problem.

I read neovim's [`README.md`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) but didn't find anything.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is no Neovim `2.0.0`. `0.3.4` is the latest. The notedown message probably comes from a plugin. https://github.com/aaren/notedown It's certainly not part of Neovim.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the plugin ([vimpyter](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/vimpyter)) which gives you this error message.

Indeed you have to download third party tool [notedown](https://github.com/aaren/notedown), it's as simple as typing in your CLI (I think you have `pip` installed):

```
$ pip install notedown
```

You can verify everything is fine by issuing:

```
$ notedown --version
```

If you have any further problems open a new issue on the github page (though I'm not too active there lately).

Comment: Thanks . I have  pip installed. Everything fine already. I did not know that the issue came from vimpyter. There for could not make use of the option you offert. As soon I knew, it was no problem any more.

Comment: Cool, could you please mark the solution so others have a definitive answer what resolves your issue,

Answer (score 0):

... So the solution is:

> Indeed you have to download third party tool >notedown, it's as simple as typing in your CLI (I >think you have pip installed):
>
> $ pip install notedown
>
> You can verify everything is fine by issuing:
>
> $ notedown --version